# php exec() returning 1 when running node js command

Tags: php, node.js, return-value

I need to run node js command from my php file. I am using exec() to do this.
Here is my script

```
<?php

$ret = exec("node -v", $out, $err);
echo print_r($out);
?>
```

Here I am getting return value 1. How to fix this?

Comment: Read the documentation on "exec"

Comment: Is `node` in the `PATH` for the user/process running PHP? (E.g. run `print_r(getenv('PATH'))` to check / compare to path you get when running `which node` on terminal)

Comment: $out contains ONLY STD_OUT, to see an err u shd run "/usr/bin/node foo.js 2>&1"

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php

Short summary:

- $ret contains last line of result
- $out array of result lines
- $err "any non-zero return value is an error" (referencing to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230620/3278963)

So 1 means "Miscellaneous errors", have you tried running the command in the shell to see what happens?